# Android support library drawables are not listed in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

`appcompat-v7` support library is included in Android Studio, some drawables in it, like `abc_ic_search_api_material`, I can manually use it in code, and you can see the preview is ok:
[image: abc_ic_search_api_material in code]

But, if I select drawable in design page, this drawable can't be found:
[image: drawable can't be found]

How to select drawable from support library, or where can I find a drawable preview list in support library?